# how to zoom a subplot in multiplot mode in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

zooming in gnu plot is done by multi plot.

But what if we have zoom a particular subplot in multi plot?

It is like a multi plot within another multi plot.

need help!

Comment: please submit your question with your valuable efforts..

Comment: "zooming in gnu plot is done by multi plot." : what does that mean on earth?

Comment: @Peaceful Probably the OP means something like http://www.gnuplotting.org/zooming-in-with-multiplot/ ?

Comment: Could you provide some data or a sketch or anything which helps us to understand what you try to achieve?

Comment: @maij  yes, that link is relevant. So for, 3,1 layout u get an image as follows : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gnuplot+multiplot&biw=1301&bih=641&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXyru6-NTRAhWFuY8KHR9hCBYQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=AoQ-BgRV89LKBM%3A. My question was if I have to insert another zoomed view of each of these three subplots, How to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a multiplot environment you can create plots wherever you want, their positions and sizes are set with the commands `set origin` and `set size`.

It is up to you whether the single plots are positioned side by side or one into another like in this example.

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "multiplot.png"

set samples 1000
set xzeroaxis

set multiplot

set origin 0,0
set size 1,1
set xrange [-15:15]
plot cos(x) * x**2, sin(x) * x**2

set nokey

set origin 0.3, 0.07
set size 0.5, 0.45
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-4:2]
set xtics 1
set ytics 2
replot

set origin 0.45, 0.14
set size 0.3, 0.2
set xrange [-0.1:0.1]
set yrange [-0.002:0.004]
set ytics 0.002
set xtics 0.1
replot

unset multiplot
```

Note that the values for `origin` and `size` are given relative to the complete picture, not relative to the previous plot.

[image: nested plots]

Comment: Thank youso much @maij . It worked perfectly. I was just thinking if the size of each subplot is same as in the multiplot command using layout 3,1 for the same canvas size?

Comment: very cool! First you set the size of the outer plot using `set size 1,1` then you set the size of the inner plot using `set size 0.5, 0.45` as a percentage of the first.